# need explanation for max and min building function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't understand the built-in functions `max` and `min` in python 2.7

```
max("sehir")
min("sehir")
```

`max` gives the letter `"s"` and `min` gives the letter `"e"`

Comment: What's unclear about that? A string is a sequence of characters and `min()` gives you the minimum value in a sequence. In this case, the character with the lowest byte value. Which coincidentally is also the alphabetically earliest character because ASCII.

Comment: Comparison is done by checking their ASCII values.

Answer (score 4):

`max` and `min` take as parameter (given you only give it one *unnamed* parameter) an *iterable*, and returns the maximum / minimum item.

A string is an iterable: if you iterate over a string, you obtain the 1-char strings that are the characters of the string.

Then `max` and `min` iterate over that iterable and returns the `max`imum or `min`imum item. For a string the *lexicographical* order is defined. So `'a' < 'b'`, and `'ab' > 'aa'`. So it is compared lexicographically, and the individual characters are compared by *ASCII code* (*Unicode code* in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)). Since all characters have are one-caracter strings. We only have to take the *ASCII code* into account here. You can inspect the [ASCII table here [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters).

So `max("sehir")` will return `'s'`, since `max(['s', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'r']) == 's'`: the maximum character in the iterable. For `min('sehir') == 'e'`, since `min(['s', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'r']) == 'e'` because it is the "*smallest*" character in the string.