# min() function in pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like the following (df1):

```
 col1 val
0  A  AX
1  A  2
2  A  11
3  A  13
4  A  BX
5  A  20
```

I want to pick the row with minimum value. Hence I wrote the following:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['col1'])['val'].min()
```

The output I get from this is,

```
col1
A 11
Name: Level, dtype: object
```

It seems like the values AX, BX is causing it to read it as object. Hence, it is doing the sort and find '11' as minimum. How to modify it, so that it can do numerical sorting and outputs ?

```
A 2
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need convert column to numeric first, because `min` working with strings nice and return characters having lowest ASCII value:

```
df2 = pd.to_numeric(df1['val'], errors='coerce').groupby(df1['col1']).min().astype(int)
print (df2)
col1
A    2
Name: val, dtype: int32
```

More information about `min` in strings is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48131239/2901002).

Comment: The link you've added is for python 2, and applies to mixed type comparison. My guess is that OP's columns are all string.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - yes, I try find better link.